# Is there any way to send TTN_NEEDTEXT notification to the child control directly?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a edit control in which i have a tooltip control. Now i want to receive the TTN_NEEDTEXT at that edit control itself instead of the parent window of that edit control. Is there any way to do that?

Here is the code of `OnCreate` of my edit control where i have created the tooltip control.

```
if(this->GetSafeHwnd() == NULL || !m_wndToolTip.Create(this))
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("FAILED to Create"), IDOK);
}
else
{
    m_wndToolTip.AddTool(this, LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK);
    m_wndToolTip.Activate(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Sub-class the edit control, and forward the message back to the parent.

Comment: I need the TTN_NEEDTEXT to come at my edit control not the parent o f that edit control. I dont understand why i should forward the message back to the parent?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread. If you have a tooltip owned by the edit control then the messages will already go to the edit control.

Comment: Apparently, that notification message is going to the parent of the edit control. I have updated the question. Please see the code.

Comment: `TTN_NEEDTEXT` is sent to the tooltip's owner window, not the parent of the owner.

Comment: But the documentation of `CTooltipCtrl::AddTool` at MSDN says different. Here is a line from documentation. -----

`lpszText
    Pointer to the text for the tool. If this parameter contains the value     LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK, TTN_NEEDTEXT notification messages go     to the parent of the window that pWnd points to.`

Comment: When you create the tooltip you get to specify its owner.

Comment: AddTool() does indeed send the notification to the parent, it doesn't matter what parent you set as owner when you create the tooltip. The behaviour of AddTool() is different from the TTM_ADDTOOL message. Furthermore, you can't use reflection because the id of the tooltip is always zero. However, there IS a way to make this work - I described it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712255/tool-tips-for-custom-made-control-using-ctooltipctrl-mfc/2713143#2713143 Basically, you have to do manually what AddTool() does, except use the HWND of the window itself (not the parent) as the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT inside the child window.

As long as the parent is a MFC window too, the WM_NOTIFY message is reflected back to the child window.